# rails callback when save fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 I've implemented a series of relationships that cause a chicken-and-egg problem when saving one complex model. (IDs are needed to relate objects, but don't exist until after they're saved.)

I'll need to create and save objects the hard way, but I need to clean up after myself if save fails, so I don't end up with a database full of empty objects.

From the model, how do I ensure my clean-up code runs if and only if a save fails? The standard list of callbacks doesn't seem to cover this case, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I wouldn't use a callback for this. I'd wrap the series of create/save statements in a transaction. If anything fails the transaction will be automatically rolled back.

Comment: The transaction is only rolled back when you use `.create!` or `.save!` though as they will raise an error while `.create` and `.save` does not.

Comment: @max you are still free to check if everything is fine and `raise Rollback` manually on any issue.

Comment: Yes @mudasobwa, but thats not automatic :)

Comment: Can you give an example of your model definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model callbacks are one of the most overused and misused features in Rails. They are great for adding simple callbacks to the lifecycle of a model but very hard to control when they are fired (like in your tests where they slow everything down) or to tap into the flow to add application logic.

If your callback ever effects more than the model defining the callback thats a very good sign that you should reconsider using a callback.

In this case what you most likely want is a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
A.transaction do 
   begin 
     a = A.create!(some_params)
     a.bs.create!(some_other_params)
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
     a
   end
end
```

This wraps the operation in a database transaction that is rolled back if either operation fails - leaving the database untouched.

You can either inline this in the controller or wrap it in a [service object](https://hackernoon.com/service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails-and-you-79ca8a1c946e).

Comment: The service object is probably the way to go.

Comment: *"Model callbacks are one of the most overused and misused features in Rails."* THIS ALL DAY LONG! You win the internet.

Comment: I like your style. I've shied away from overuse of callbacks in the past, to the extent of implementing an observer pattern in a particularly nasty codebase, to avoid callback loops and other callback issues. I felt tied to callbacks here as I'm using ActiveAdmin, but in theory I could override the save method and delegate to another object.